# Divisor of given order in short intervals

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisors-multiples, sieve-theory, prime-gaps

Is the following Open question or Conjecture already known, or eventually settled ?

**Open question :** For sufficiently large $x$ there is at least a positive integer in the interval $[x,x+\log^2(x)]$ that has a divisor in the interval $[x^{1/3}, 2x^{1/3}]$.

Possibly, weaker statements with $x^{\varepsilon}$ instead of $\log^2x$, and/or larger intervals for the divisors (as for exemple  $[x^{1/3}, x^{1/2}]$ instead of  $[x^{1/3}, 2x^{1/3}]$) could be of interest in this regard.

Comment: Just a quick idea: from Erdős-Kac theorem the average number of prime factors of an integer around $x$ is $\log\log x$ so that this number of factors is not upper bounded in $[x,x+\log^{2} x]$ as $x$ tends to infinity. We may consider the "factor spread" of an integer $n$ as the difference between its largest prime factor and its smallest one. Could we prove this quantity is small enough, say $O_{\varepsilon}(x^{\varepsilon})$ or $o(\log^{2} x)$, the $k$-th smallest prime factor of $n$ with $k:=(\Omega(n)-\Omega(n) \mod 3)/3$ may give a solution.